# Workflow builder ui in flutter

Tags: flutter

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I782n.png)I would love to do something like this in flutter…workflow builder

Can not seem to find a plugin that can pull it off too

How do you connect the containers with lines like in the image above.

Comment: Flutter 3.13 added `TwoDimensionalScrollable`.

Comment: You can use native flutter widget, `ReorderableListView` to achieve it

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.